# ZeroVM import error: No module named thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pthreads, zerocloud, zerovm

When working on a small [ZeroVM](http://zerovm.org/) application that will run on [ZeroCloud](https://github.com/zerovm/zerocloud/) (that is, the ZeroVM integration with [Swift](http://swift.openstack.org/)), and trying to import the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing) module, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import multiprocessing
  File "/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 38, in <module>
    import threading        # we want threading to install it's
  File "/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 6, in <module>
    import thread
ImportError: No module named thread
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support for threading or multiprocessing in ZeroVM. The [Python status document](https://github.com/zerovm/zpython2/blob/master/status.md) lists both modules as unsupported.

The ZeroVM platform is a single process, single threaded environment. However, there is a [pthreads port](http://zerovm.org/architecture.htm) available. Instead of normal premeptive multithreading, this port uses cooperative multitasking instead. It might be possible to use this to enable some form of threading in the ZeroVM Python port.